# Remote EJB with a JTA transaction causes java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection

Tags: mysql, jpa, jakarta-ee, glassfish, xa

I have two pure Java EE applications, RemoteApp and ClientApp. I want to use ClientApp to access RemoteApp through a remote EJB to perfom some persistent action. I using JTA and CMT but when invoke anyone RemoteApp method in a Persistence Context and perform some Database action, the server simply does not respond until a transaction timeOut occurs.

To materialize what I said, I'll show the core code:

**RemoteApp code:**

```
package br.com;
@Remote
interface IRemote {void method();}

@Stateless

//I explained the use of these below annotations only for clarity
@TransactionManagement(value = TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER) 
@TransactionAttribute(value = TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
class Remote implements IRemote { 

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

void method(){
    em.persist(new MyEntity()); //A simple action just to example a Persistence Context situation
}
```

Persistence.xml of RemoteApp:

```
<persistence-unit name="remoteAppPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/remoteAppDS</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.table-creation-suffix" value="engine=InnoDB"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

Datasource of Glassfish domain of RemoteApp (config.xml):

```
<jdbc-connection-pool datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource" name="remoteAppPool" res-type="javax.sql.XADataSource">
      <property name="user" value="user"></property>
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://remoteApp:3306/remoteAppDB"></property>
      <property name="password" value="password"></property>
</jdbc-connection-pool>

<jdbc-resource pool-name="remoteAppPool" jndi-name="jdbc/remoteAppDS"></jdbc-resource>
```

**Client-App code:**

```
@Stateless
class LocalBean {
    @EJB(mappedName = "corbaname:iiop:server.com:3700#java:global/RemoteApp/Remote!br.com.IRemote"
    private IRemote remote;

    @TransactionAttribute
    void testMethod(){remote.method();}
}
```

When ClientApp invokes a RemoteApp method **i got a exception after 30 minutes** (I can't found a way to decrease this time):

> javax.ejb.EJBException: Unable to complete container-managed transaction.
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:734)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:507)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4600)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2108)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2078)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy283.testar(Unknown Source)
>       at br.com.ejb.**EJB31_Generated__LocalBean__Intf____Bean**.method(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:76)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:148)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:191)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:243)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:103)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:493)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:104)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1580)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:258)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:652)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:591)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   Caused by: javax.transaction.SystemException: org.omg.CORBA.UNKNOWN: ----------BEGIN server-side stack trace----------
>   org.omg.CORBA.UNKNOWN: ADVERTÊNCIA: 00010002: Unknown user exception thrown by the server - exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException; message: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.0.v20170811-d680af5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
>   Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: ADVERTÊNCIA: 00410019: Communications timeout waiting for response.  Exceeded 1.800.000 milliseconds  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 19 completed: Maybe
>   Error Code: 0
>   Call: INSERT INTO MYENTITY (NAME) VALUES (?)
>       bind => [bla]
>   Query: InsertObjectQuery(br.com.MyEntity@0)  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 2 completed: Maybe
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy194.runtimeexception(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.convertThrowableToSystemException(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1764)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleThrowableDuringServerDispatch(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1714)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleThrowableDuringServerDispatch(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1679)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:255)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1550)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1426)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(MessageMediatorImpl.java:931)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:213)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:695)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(MessageMediatorImpl.java:497)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.doWork(MessageMediatorImpl.java:2223)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
>   Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.0.v20170811-d680af5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
>   Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: ADVERTÊNCIA: 00410019: Communications timeout waiting for response.  Exceeded 1.800.000 milliseconds  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 19 completed: Maybe
>   Error Code: 0
>   Call: INSERT INTO MYENTITY (NAME) VALUES (?)
>       bind => [bla]
>   Query: InsertObjectQuery(br.com.MyEntity@0)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl$1.handleException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:772)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.AbstractSynchronizationListener.handleException(AbstractSynchronizationListener.java:275)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.AbstractSynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(AbstractSynchronizationListener.java:170)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.JTASynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(JTASynchronizationListener.java:68)
>       at com.sun.jts.jta.SynchronizationImpl.before_completion(SynchronizationImpl.java:99)
>       at com.sun.jts.CosTransactions.RegisteredSyncs.distributeBefore(RegisteredSyncs.java:141)
>       at com.sun.jts.CosTransactions.TopCoordinator.beforeCompletion(TopCoordinator.java:2548)
>       at com.sun.jts.CosTransactions.CoordinatorSynchronizationImpl.before_completion(CoordinatorSynchronizationImpl.java:165)
>       at org.omg.CosTransactions.SynchronizationPOA._invoke(SynchronizationPOA.java:39)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:528)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:199)
>       ... 9 more
>   Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.0.v20170811-d680af5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
>   Internal Exception: **java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: ADVERTÊNCIA: 00410019: Communications timeout waiting for response.  Exceeded 1.800.000 milliseconds**  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 19 completed: Maybe
>   Error Code: 0
>   Call: INSERT INTO MYENTITY (NAME) VALUES (?)
>       bind => [bla]
>   Query: InsertObjectQuery(br.com.MyEntity@0)
>       ... repeated log

**Here are some observations:**

1. Both Apps are in different containers and security configs are disable.
2. I have been used Glassfish Server 5.0 with Java EE Specification 8.0
3. I have ben used mysql 5.7 with XA Protocol and engine InnoDB on tables
4. If I don't use a Persistence Context / persistent operation **it works**
5. If I use BMT **it works**
6. **I'm insisting on this approach because i want to control transaction by client, otherwise I would use a SIMPLE web service**

CMT = Container Management Transaction = TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER

BMT = Bean Management Transaction = TransactionManagementType.BEAN

**What I think is causing the problem:**

- I suspect MySql is crashing in commit / rollback (But i was tried with Derby and same problem happened)
- A problem with XA MySql DataSource
- MySql transaction support. I suspected that InnoDB engine would solve... I was wrong.

Comment: A thread dump from both sides would be useful

Comment: `name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource"` - how is `MysqlXADataSource` a JDBC driver?

Comment: Crizzis. Reading this link, exists this XA Datasource.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-installing-classpath.html